# My notebook's display frequently turns off for a moment? With external screen, it's even more frequent

Tags: laptop, display, external-display

Currently I use my notebook **without an external display**, and the following happens:

- a **few weeks ago** it started to **lose signal occasionally**.
- And it's a **really short period**, because after my screen goes black, it instantly "starts to come back".

I tried using this **display via HDMI**: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/UM.HV0EE.P01

And it seems that it's **much more regular** on the 2K display, than on my 1080p integrated screen.

Here is what I've experienced with an external display:

- Another has just happened, and it was simultanous with the **refrigerator's fans** turning off. Later, it happened again when the fridgerator turned its fans on. I will watch out whether there are more "suspicous" things or not.
- Now for 3 minutes, it happened like every 45 seconds. And I didn't notice any electric change in the room.
- I pulled out the **charger** from the notebook, to see if there is any difference, and after a few minutes, it began to turn off like **every 4 seconds**, sometimes they even overlapped, causing long black screens.
- It also seemed like when **I moved the mouse**, it got black. I **pulled out** the mouse, and the frequent black screen **suddenly stopped**.
- Then I **put it back** after half a minute, and it's still not that frequent, but there are black screens again.

Comment: Is the charger grounded (3rd prong)? If you're using any power extension cords, are they grounded? Is the refrigerator nearby? Are any computer-related cables running near the refrigerator? Anything else except for the mouse plugged into USB?

Comment: The order of plugged in stuff in the notebook are: charger, hdmi, keyboard usb, mouse usb, empty usb, jack for external speakers. Everything is grounded, and I haven't changed anything in my setup for months. I use the same power extension for my desktop PC as well, no issues there. No, the refrigerator is like 3-4 meters away from my workstation, and no computer related cables there.

Comment: @gronostaj as it turns out, this still happens, even without an external display. But it's much less frequent. Updated the original post.

Comment: Seems like the electricity in your house is not well isolated, so turning appliances on/off can cause electrical surges, which is quite dangerous. I suggest to protect the computer with a UPS.

Comment: just to be 100% sure, the screen blanking occurs whether or not it is plugged into an electrical outlet?  What happens if your remove the notebooks battery, but plug it into an outlet?

Comment: When I was on an external display, I plugged out the charger, and still happened, maybe the electric problems affected the display as well.
But now I am at a friend's house, without external display, on charger, and it happened as well, but only once in 6 hours.
When I get home, I'll try using the external display without batteries.

Comment: @Tudvari Hello. What you describe looks like a video driver crash. I suggest you to check **Event Viewer** for events about the video driver crashing (specially events with ID 4101 or 1000).

Comment: In addition to getting a UPS, I think you should check your Power Supply Unit (PSU). It might be glitching out.

Comment: I've ordered a UPS, and I will check the event viewer. New info: I was in another house for a whole weekend, with external display, and the screen went black zero times. However, I can reproduce it manually now in my apartment: I have my speakers plugged in to the same extension, and if I plug it out, as soon as I plug it back, my screen goes black. All the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems seem to be power-oriented:

- The fact that turning electrical appliances on/off in the house causes
  problems may mean that the electricity in your house is not well isolated
  and some appliances cause strong electrical surges, which is quite dangerous.
  In that case the computer needs to be protected with a UPS
  or at least with a surge protector.
- The fact that the computer cannot work without the charger may mean that the
  battery is nearly dead.
- As this happens very rarely outside of your house, but still happens,
  and that connecting devices also has a negative effect,
  might mean that your Power Supply Unit (PSU) is weakening.

If the computer is new, use the warranty to have it replaced.
A repair-shop will have the tools and replacement parts to better analyze the
problem. However, if the computer is quite old, ask for estimates for the 
repairs to see if the investment is worthwhile.

Comment: I've bought a high quality UPS, but it didn't solve the issue. Maybe it's a bit less frequent, but I've been using it only for a few hours. I don't know why in the other house happened zero times over 20 hours, an in another only once over 30 hours.

Comment: The UPS may not catch all possible problems. I assume the 3 houses are on different electrical distribution networks.

Comment: Yes they are. But as it seems, the UPS lowered the number of problems to a marginal degree.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, it doesn't help at all as it seems.

Comment: The UPS is always good to have, especially when having electricity problems. There are other possibilities above, but testing them all will cost.

Comment: I think I will delay testing it. Soon I'll go back to the office anyway, so I don't have to use my notebook at home. And then if further symptons appear, it will be easier to find the issue.